# Solve D.E using integrating factor: $ y dx - (y^2+x^2+x) dy=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve using integrating factor:  $$ y dx - (y^2+x^2+x) dy=0$$

My attempt first get the D.E into the form

$\frac{dy}{dx} +p(x)y(x)=q(x)$ so

So my integrating factor is $e^{\int p(x) dx}$

$$ ydx - (y^2+x^2+x) dy=0$$

$$ -ydx + (y^2+x^2+x)dy=0$$

$$ \frac{-y}{y^2+x^2+x} + \frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{1}{y^2+x^2+x} \cdot y =0 $$

However how can I have an integrating factor of

$e^{\int - \frac{1}{y^2+x^2+x}  dx}$ ?

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: p must be a function of x, not y

Comment: @vvnitram yes I understand that but how I do get my d.e into that form , it seems like I cannot do that

Comment: i have got an ugly solution

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this method via use of exact differentials, if you like:

$$ y dx - (y^2+x^2+x) dy=0$$
$$ y dx - x dy =(y^2+x^2) dy$$
$$ \frac{y dx - x dy}{(y^2+x^2)} = dy$$
$$d\left(\arctan\frac{x}{y}\right)=dy$$
$$\boxed{y=\left(\arctan\frac{x}{y}\right)+c}$$

This is the required solution.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you. My book however says the integrating factor should be $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ how is this possible?